# JTable not updating after inserting a row into database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I want to constantly update my `JTable` whenever one or more rows has been inserted to MYSQL database.

I populated my `JTable` with the data that is already in the database using `tableModel()` method, and `changed()` method to update my `JTable` if a new row is inserted into the database.

I tried `fireTableDataChanged()`, `setModel()` and `repaint()` on the `JTable` inside my `change()` method but it doesn't do anything.

Here is my code below:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JPanel{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane pane;

    public Test() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        try {
            table = new JTable(tableModel());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        changed(table);
        pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(pane);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public DefaultTableModel tableModel() throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection myConn = null;

        try {
            //connect to database
            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","root","abcd");

            //Create SQL statement
            Statement stmt = (Statement) myConn.createStatement();

            //Execute Query
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT field1,field2 FROM test");
            //Process result set

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();

        // names of columns
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        // data of the table
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }
        myConn.close();
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        return dtm ;
    }

    public void changed(JTable table) {
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
        table.repaint();
        table.setModel(dtm);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new Test());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(510,390);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: You only need to call table.setModel(dtm). There is no relationship between the JTable or the database, so when the database is updated you will need to manually update the JTable (calling your changed method for example)

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the DefaultTableModel associated with you JTable anywhere after the initial load. You will have to programmatically update the DefaultTableModel to have the updates propagated to the JTable. eg:

```
void changed(JTable table) 
{ 
   DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel(); 
   Vector data = dtm.getDataVector(); 
   Vector data2 = (Vector)data.get(0); 
   data2.clear(); 
   data2.add("changed data1"); 
   data2.add("changed data2"); 
   dtm.fireTableDataChanged(); 
   table.repaint(); 
   table.setModel(dtm); 
}
```

The above code will reflect the changes. You may have to maintain your row-data in the default table model using a uniquqe key (say in a map) and then retreive that row data (which is a vector object) and then modify the vector with the updated changes. This will reflect on the JTable

Comment: every code line after ` DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();`  are wrong change to, replace those code lines with `dtm.setRowCount(0)`, then add `columns` and `data` to `DefaultTableModel`, `DefaultTableModel` to `JTable`,

Comment: otherwise to delete your answer, all those nonsenses